# Adding a editable TextView on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

As my first Objective-C project ever I need to implement the following on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

[image]

You can ignore everything at the second line that says "Sikkerhed". All I want is a new view to pop up along with the keyboard when a cell in my `UITableView` is pressed. The data being set and the text being shown will change depending on which row was selected. How do I go about implementing something like this? Do I need a new `UIViewController` for this `view`?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to:

1. create an UITableViewController
2. Set the tableview's style to grouped

   In your code:
3. Fill the tableview like in this tutorial:
   http://windrealm.org/tutorials/uitableview_uitextfield_form.php
4. Present your viewController in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

   - Create an instance of UINavigationController and set the modalPresentationStyle to fill only a part of the screen:

     ```
     navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
     ```

     (You can find more information about modalViewControllers and ModalPresentionStyle e.g. [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/05/03/ipad-modal-view-controllers.html))
   - Push an instance of your custom UITableViewController on the navigation controller:

     ```
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController];
     ```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you could do

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // find with cell has been pressed
   // with indexPath.row

   // instantiate your new viewController depending on the logic of the cell selected
   // for example
   MyCustomViewController* mcvc = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:bundle]

   // do ur logic
   // Note, u should get your viewController embedded into a uinavigationContrlller, 
   // so you can
   [self.navigationController pushViewController: [mcvc autorelease] animated:YES];

}
```